# Python - Anaconda - How to remove anaconda from Path (I dont want to uninstall anaconda)

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I have a windows 10 laptop, and i needed to install anaconda for some project, i used add to path option in the installation but now, i want to use the normal python path instead of the anaconda one, can someone please guide me.

Comment: just update the python path

Comment: how to do that can you please tell @deadshot

Comment: @deadshot pleas tell

Answer (score 2):

To edit your environment variable:
**Control Panel** > **System and Security** > **System** > **Advanced system settings** > **Environment variables**

Now you should see 2 tables one for user variables and the other for system variables. In both tables there is a variable called Path. Try to edit both, if you find some anaconda path in one of them you can remove them. If you don't want to remove them but still want to use another python interpreter you can move the anaconda path under the python path.

PS: Normally you should only edit user variables, anaconda path will not be set in system variables.